# WSO2 ESB unable to un-deploy endpoints, localentries with CAR undeployment

Tags: deployment, wso2-esb

Scenario to replicate the issue with wso2 esb 4.8.0
create the CAR file by selecting all the proxy services, sequences, endpoints, and local entries.
Deploy the car on to WSO2 ESB with console.

This makes deployment of all the artifacts into server.

Now try to un-deploy the car from the console. 
Except endpoints, local-entries, everything will be un-deployed.

Please let us know the way to resolve this issue without server restart.

Comment: did you do any midification using web based management console?

Comment: No, i tried without doing any modification from admin console. it is not un-deploying...

Comment: If we do any modification from admin console it will create the new version endpoint file. so it tried without modifying from console.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug in WSO2, if u try same thing from wso2 web management console it shows similar behaviour, As far i have researched on the topic WSO2 by default does not un-deploy the **Registry Artifacts** like **endpoints** or **local-entries.** Every time you re-deploy the CAR file it overwrites the contents of all the registry artifacts.